# "invalid record length at 0/D00027B: wanted 24, got 0" after restoring pg_basebackup as a second time"

Tags: postgresql

I am encountering an issue while attempting to restore a PostgreSQL database using pg_basebackup for the second time. The error message I'm receiving is "invalid record length at 0/D00027B: wanted 24, got 0." This seems to indicate a problem with the record length at a specific position during the restoration process.

Has anyone else encountered this error, and what steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve it? I've already verified the integrity of the initial backup and retried the restoration process without success. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have been following the postgresql documention specificlly for this [topic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html) in order to create an offline mechanism for syncing data. I have created two postgresql clusters, one is the primary and slave, I have created base backup of the pramiry to the slave and I have added data to the priamry and restore the slave as the first time and everything went successfull, However when I have added data to the primary, the restore command raised the above error, and did not update the slave data as the primary.

In the Primary's postgresql.conf:

```
wal_level = "replica"
archive_mode = on
archive_command = "copy %p c:\\Users\\myuser\\desktop\\pg_log_primary\\%f"
```

And in the slave's postgresql.conf:

```
wal_level = "replica"
restore_command = "copy c:\\Users\\myuser\\desktop\\pg_log_primary\\%f %p"
recover_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, it's common information message about reaching of the end of WAL records sequence in the last WAL segment (WAL file).

So two facts in the sentense "the restore command raised the above error, and did not update the slave data as the primary" are independent of each other.

Seeing you are using synchronisation through log-shipping. In that case delay of synchronisation, among other things, depends on the value of `archive_timeout` on the master. If it set to 0, it's may take forever to put next WAL segment into archive (and to get it on the slave, as result) in the system without constant load (without enough load to fillup WAL segment in mean time). So, works fine on high-load systems, and has delays when there's no enough changes in WAL sequence for generation of a new segment every few seconds.

On the master set `archive_timeout` to number of seconds after that it should be forced creation of the next WAL segment (`120` should be good for beginning, maybe even less, but avoid to use really small values like less than `30`), and reload postgres configuration (`select pg_reload_conf();`).

Or, in general, switch from log-shgipping replication to streaming replication, if it's possible for you. It does not rely on waiting for the WAL segment to appear in the archive, but using direct connetion to the master instead and doing instant WAL sequence stream to the slave.

Comment: The issue is occurred when I call signal.conf second time, it fails, doesn't synchronize the changes, and raises the above message.

Comment: No idea what is signal.conf, sorry. And can't find any info about it even.

Comment: I meant by the signal.conf is recovery.signal